# How to find if an ID is present in a variable which has HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to find if the ID is present in a variable which has HTML content.

ID name is getting attached to DIV element by dynamic variables.

```
strHTML = "<div id='"+var1+var2+"'>"
```

Now, i like to check if a particular ID is present in strHTML.

How do i do that.?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

Added actual code for more clarity...

```
for(data in ArrayOFObjects)

var splitDate = ArrayOFObjects[data]["NewsDate"].split("-");

**if(!$(strHTML).find('#'+splitDate[1]+splitDate[0]))** // if condition is not correct, just my try
{   

strHTML += "<div id='"+splitDate[1]+splitDate[0]+"></div>"
                                                       }
                                                        }
```

So when the next **for in** loop happens, i like to check if the **ID already exist** in **strHTML**, if it exists then i do not want the **DIV creation to happen**

Thanks

Comment: You'd be better off remembering whether you put the id value in there in the first place.

Comment: This question is a little vague, I'm not sure I really get it. Its motivation might be a little exotic, too.

Comment: Please provide sample content what will be present in var1 and var2

Comment: @Pointy This becomes a problem when using dynamically generated code or using a library accepting HTML elements and reacting to `class`es and `id`s, which is a fairly common thing to do.

Comment: @KenB well the part that smells to me is wanting to know about the code in its string form (if that's what's being asked here; it's not clear).  Once it's in the DOM, then I agree that using ordinary DOM inspection tools makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Pointy That's a fair point. I agree that, using jQuery, it would be best to interpret the code and use normal selectors.

Comment: @All.. Sorry for being vague.. Have added the actual code to give more clarity to the question..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if your HTML contains an element whose id contains some value, you may do

```
var $elements = $('[id~="'+someValue+'"]', '<div>'+strHTML+'</div>');
var doContain = $elements.length>0;
```

If your string strHTML is really something like `"<div id='"+var1+var2+"'>"`, then simply use a regex :

```
var id = strHTML.match(/["']([^\"']*)["']/)[1];
```

and look in `id` for your id.

Comment: Won't that only look in the *contents* of the element?

Comment: @Pointy Yes, but the question is so vague that I inferred it was the requirement. I'm probably wrong.

Comment: `strHTML` is neither a DOM element nor a jQuery object. It's just a string, so I don't believe it can be used as `context`

Comment: @Boaz Type this in your console : `$('a', '<div><a href=toto>U</a></div>')`.

Comment: @dystroy I stand corrected. I misunderstood what the documentation of the jQuery constructor meant by `element` as a possible value for the `context` argument.

Comment: @Boaz You didn't misunderstand, it's just not documented that it also accepts a string. There are other undocumented aspects of jQuery, though I can't think of a specific example off the top of my head.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes, I see what you mean now. It should also be documented that `context` accepts what jQuery calls [`htmlString`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString)

Comment: @All.. Sorry for being vague.. Have added the actual code to give more clarity to the question..

Answer (score 0):

You can use javaScript's search function:

```
var n=strHTML.search(var1+var2);
if (n > -1)
{
  // found it!
}
```